# I deleted steamapps to uninstall steam can i get my games back though

Tags: steam

I deleted every folder to uninstall steam including steamapps I installed steam again and my games are gone can I get them back or no?

Comment: Have you logged into your account?

Comment: By getting your games back, do you mean being able to install them again or getting any saves back?

Comment: When looking at your library, are you sure you do *not* have 'Installed' selected? You will need to have either 'Games' or 'Recent' or almost any other category selected to see uninstalled games.

Comment: You just need to log in. After that Steam will sync itself and you will be able to download any game that you've owned previously. This does not incluse shortcuts to non-stesm games

Answer (score 4):

All games that are purchased through steam are stored in your steam library. 
If you log into the program using your username and password (after reinstalling steam) all of your games will be available for download there!

If you are sure that you are logged into the correct account, and don't have "installed" selected in your library (thanks @DJPirtu), try reinstalling steam. If this still doesn't work [contact steam support](https://support.steampowered.com/).

Comment: when i go on steam the games are not there to download

Comment: did you install them from disk and are you sure you're logged into the right account?

Comment: I buyed them of the store and im sure im in the right account

Comment: Then contact steam support

Comment: I have, do you think could give my games back If I have proof I had buyed them

Comment: And how long would it take?

Comment: @JamieBarnes Yes, Steam will take quite a while to get back to you, but if you have proof of purchase they can indeed give you your games back. However, it's more likely that you have just missed something when logging in and/or browsing your games.

Comment: @JamieBarnes the key is persistence, Steam support is notoriously awful but they do eventually generally do what you need them to.